# Поиска минимального числа среди последних 4 элементов массива на ассемблере

Tags: массивы, ассемблер

Есть код для поиска максимального числа среди всех элементов:

```
.model small  
.stack  
.data  
    message db "max = ", 30h,30h,"$"  
    string1 db 99,67,34,87,25,11,85,76,98  
    res db ?  
    strResult db 16 dup (0) ; string buffer to store result  
.code  
main proc  
    mov ax,seg message  
    mov ds,ax  
    mov cx,09h  
    mov bl,00h  
    lea si,string1  
up:  
    mov al,[si]  
    cmp al,bl  
    jl next  
    mov bl,al  
next:  
    inc si  
    dec cx  
    jnz up  
    mov res,bl  
    xor ax,ax  
    mov ax,bx  
    mov cx,10  
    xor bx,bx  
divide:  
    xor dx,dx  
    div cx  
    push dx  
    inc bx  
    test ax,ax  
    jnz divide  
    mov cx,bx  
    lea si,strResult  
next_digit:  
    pop ax  
    add al,'0'  
    mov [si],al  
    inc si  
    loop next_digit  
    lea di,message  
    lea si,strResult  
    mov bx,[si]  
    mov [di+6],bx  
    mov ah,09  
    lea dx,message  
    int 21h  
main endp  
end main
```

Comment: Допустим, есть код. А вопрос в чем?

Comment: Заменить jnz на jz и jl на jge. В общем, то же самое, только наоборот.